# Anyone knows how to fix compile error: LNK2005? (Source Code inside)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have the below code in stdafx.h.

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    DWORD   address;
    DWORD   size;
    char    file[64];
    DWORD   line;
} ALLOC_INFO;

typedef list<ALLOC_INFO*> AllocList;
//AllocList *allocList;
```

Without the commented code (last line), it compiles just fine. But when I add the commented code, Im getting the following error.

> error LNK2005: "class std::list >
>   * allocList" (?allocList@@3PAV?$list@PAUALLOC_INFO@@V?$allocator@PAUALLOC_INFO@@@std@@@std@@A)
>   already defined in test.obj

Im using Visual Studio .NET 2003. Anyone has any idea what that is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't put *definitions* in header files, just *declarations*. Declarations specify that something exists while definitions actually define them (by allocating space). For example `typedef`, `extern` and function prototypes are all declarations, while things like `struct`, `int` and function bodies are definitions.

What's happening is that you're most likely including stdafx.h in multiple compilation units (C++ source files) and each of the resulting object files is getting its own copy of `allocList`.

Then when you link the objects together, there's two (or more) things called `allocList`, hence the link error.

You would be better off *declaring* the variable:

```
extern AllocList *allocList;
```

in your header file and *defining* it somewhere in a C++ source file (such as a `main.cpp`):

```
AllocList *allocList;
```

That way, every compilation unit that includes `stdafx.h` will know about the external variable, but it's only defined in one compilation unit.

Based on your further information:

> I was trying to follow http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks.shtml, I assume that all those code are meant to be placed in the stdafx.h. Any other alternatives, pax?

My response is as follows.

I wouldn't put them in `stdafx.h` myself since I think that uses some MS magic for pre-compiled headers.

Make a separate header file `mymemory.h` and put your function prototypes in it, for example (note that this has no *body*):

```
inline void * __cdecl operator new(
    unsigned int size,
    const char *file,
    int line);
```

Also in that header, put the other prototypes for `AddTrack()`, `DumpUnfreed()`, etc., and the `#define`, `typedef` and `extern` statements:

```
extern AllocList *allocList;
```

Then, in a new file `mymemory.cpp` (which also contains `#include "mymemory.h"`), put the actual definition of `allocList` along with all the real functions (not just the prototypes) and add that file to your project.

Then, `#include "mymemory.h"` in every source file in which you need to track memory (probably all of them). Because there are no definitions in the header file, you won't get duplicates during the link and because the declarations are there, you won't get undefined references either.

Keep in mind that this won't track memory leaks in code that you don't compile (e.g., third-party libraries) but it should let you know about your own problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to follow this [article](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks.shtml), I assume that all those code are meant to be placed in the stdafx.h. Any other alternatives pax?

Comment: This should really have been a comment to my answer (so I get notified) but I'll answer it anyway. That code will work if there's a single C++ source file including stdafx.h. Otherwise it'll get link errors - I suspect it was never tested in a real installation with multi-files.

Comment: Suggest you email the author (dpicco -at- cs.mun.ca) to see what they're on about.

Comment: For a suggested fix, see my answer. Basically all the functions and allocList definition should be in a separate C++ source file, you can leave the function prototypes and an extern marker for allocList in stdafx.h (although you may want to move them to another header file).